# How to access Google Bigquery data from pandas, based on where clause from a local csv

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

So I have a local dataframe called ***Frames*** which has a column *item*.
I want to extract information  from a Google BigQuery dataset ***Sales***. ***Sales*** has a column *itemnumber* and I want to get only those values that exist in ***Frames***.*item*

I need to execute something along these lines:

```
frames=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path,index_col=None)
df = gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM Usales.Sales where itemnumber in frames.item LIMIT 1000', project_id='Project')
```

Comment: Can you put Frames into bigquery and then do you: `SELECT * FROM Usales.Sales where itemnumber in (select distinct item from frames)`

Comment: In theory, yes I could but have access restrictions and hence this is not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frames=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path,index_col=None)
df = gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM Usales.Sales where itemnumber in ({}) LIMIT 1000'.format(', '.join('"{0}"'.format(item) for item in frames['item'].tolist())), project_id='project')
```

Comment: The portion which uses the join needs to be tweaked.
As of now   `format(','.join(frames['item'].tolist()))` produces an array like:
(abc,cde,efg,xyz) rather than producing something of this sort:
("abc","cde","xyz")

Comment: You are right - I edited my response, should be OK now.

Comment: Cool, this is what worked for me, it was missing a pesky bracket somewhere in the middle.


`df = gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM Usales.Sales where itemnumber in ({}) LIMIT 1000'.format(', '.join('"{0}"'.format(item) for item in frames['item'].tolist())), project_id='project')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the portion that applies GBQ part from pandas DataFrame apply part.

E.g.

```
def getDataForAnItem(item):
  # process item using gbq
  print(item)
  return  gbq.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM Usales.Sales where itemnumber in frames."+str(item)+" LIMIT 1000', project_id='Project')

frames=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path,index_col=None)
resultDF = df['item'].apply(getDataForAnItem)
```

Comment: This works but rather than passing an array of strings to BiqQuery and requesting for 1000 rows in total, it iterates through the Frames.Item column one at a time and passes 1000 rows for each item.